# Segmentation fault, but why ? Ubuntu Intel

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

Im new to assembly programming, and ive came across a problem, I get this error :

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. LoopNextChar ()
>   at XXX.s:136 136      movq    %rax, (%r11)

Here is the code:

```
getText:

    xorq    %r11, %r11
    xorq    %rax, %rax  
    xorq    %r10, %r10
    xorq    %r9, %r9
    movq    %rsi, %r10
    movq    %rdi, %r11

LoopNextChar:
    cmpq    $0, %r10
    je  returnTxt

    cmpq    $63, buffInPtr
    je  inImage

    sub     $8, %rsp
    call    getChar
    add $8, %rsp

    cmpq    $0, %rax
    je  returnTxt

    movq    %rax, (%r11)
    incq    %r11
    incq    %r9
    incq    %r10
    jmp     LoopNextChar


returnTxt:  
    movq    %r9, %rax
    ret
//

getChar:
    movq    $buffInPtr,%r10
    movq    $buffIn,%r9
    xorq    %rax,%rax
    cmpq    $63,(%r10)
    je  inImage
    addq    (%r10),%r9
    movzbq  (%r9),%rax
    addq    $1,%r10
    ret
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and comment your code especially if you want others to help. As to the fault, obviously `r11` has invalid address which may be because you have an overflow or the caller passed in a wrong argument to start with. PS: it's also suspicious that you write 64 bits to a pointer that only increments by 1 (but this does not fault).

Comment: So this can be caused by other parts of the code, that doesnt use rax ?

Comment: Since `rax` is used for exiting the loop, if that gets a wrong value it might not exit the loop in time, thus incrementing `r11` until it overruns the buffer. It's also suspicious that `buffInPtr` is not adjusted anywhere. But then, you haven't shown complete code.

Comment: buffInPtr is being adjusted with addq $1,%r10...

Comment: That doesn't change `buffInPtr` itself, unless you write it back, which you don't. So the `cmpq    $63, buffInPtr` always sees the same unchanged value. Use a debugger to step through the code already.

Comment: I love you Sir, my problems were fixed when I used incq buffInPtr instead :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the buffInPtr, it was never incremented... To fix the issue I worte incq buffInPtr instead of addq $1, %r10

Comment: Instead of incrementing a memory operand, keep that variable in a register.  Change the compares and stuff to use that register.  x86-64 has 15 GP registers.  It's silly to keep a loop variable in memory, because `inc [mem]` has a 6 cycle latency, limiting your loop to running at one iteration per 6 cycles.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for how to write good asm that runs fast.